# Linux gRPC & Conan Version incompatibility

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc, conan

I am trying to use **gRPC** to create a simple rpc mechanism for a project. I started by cloning **gRPC** from **github** and selecting the tag for version `1.47.1`.

I built and installed this on **Ubuntu** as per the instructions, by pulling from GitHub and selecting the tag for `v1.47.1`

I then created a simple file, e.g.

```
// Latest proto standard
syntax = "proto3";

package packageName;

// TODO Define service name
service ConfigService {
    rpc GET (GetRequest) returns (GetResponse);
}

message GetRequest {
    string id = 1;
}

message GetResponse {
    string value = 1;
}
```

Next step is to generate the C++ code

```
GEN_GRPC_SERVER_DIR=./gen_grpc_server_base
GEN_GRPC_MESSAGE_DIR=./gen_grpc_message_defs
mkdir -p $GEN_GRPC_SERVER_DIR $GEN_GRPC_MESSAGE_DIR
protoc --proto_path=. --cpp_out=$GEN_GRPC_MESSAGE_DIR \
        --grpc_out=$GEN_GRPC_SERVER_DIR \
        --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=/usr/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin \
        ./simple.proto
```

I am using **CMake** with **Conan** to build. My `conanfile.txt` includes the line:
`grpc/1.47.1`

Unfortunately when I try and build it using **CMake** with **Conan** I get an error about versioning. Which is triggered by the following generated code:

```
#include <google/protobuf/port_def.inc>
#if PROTOBUF_VERSION < 3019000
#error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
#error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
#error your headers.
#endif
#if 3019004 < PROTOBUF_MIN_PROTOC_VERSION
#error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is
#error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please
#error regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc.
#endif
```

When I checked the file `port_def.inc` in the clone of grpc from github it shows that the version is `301900`

When I check the version reported from the file `port_def.inc` from my `~/.conan/data/grpc` directory is `3021000` hence the error message.

I assumed the version would match because my Conan file states the version as `1.47.1` and the tag of **gRPC** from **GitHub** I selected is `v1.47.1`.

Further investigation of the GitHi clone reveals that the file `port_def.inc` comes from the the submodule for `protobuf`. The tag for `protobuf` that has a version of `port_def.inc` whcih has the correct version is tagged `v3.21.0` which is not the version used by **gRPC** `v1.47.1`

**How do I pull and build a version of gRPC from GitHub which matches the version used by Conan?** or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either override the protobuf version in your conan recipe to `3.19.4` or probably better to update the git submodule in grpc/third_party/protobuf to `3.21.0`:

```
cd grpc/third_party/protobuf
git checkout v3.21.0
```

Comment: Will simply updating the sub module in  my clone of gRPC cause any other issues?

Comment: I presume you're only using it to generate the code? You possibly don't even need a checkout, you can just use the executables from your conan version

Comment: Just tried and it works, thanks!

Comment: Bit confused why the version is incorrect out of the box though..

Comment: conan regularly updates its dependencies, if grpc hasn't been updated for a while but its dependencies have then you should expect the conan version to have different dependent versions than the release. This is part of the advantage of conan, it's easy to update dependencies (assuming they're compatible with the current version)